# group by multiple Columns and Select specific columns

Tags: c#, entity-framework, group-by, linq-to-entities, multiple-columns

How can I do GroupBy Multiple Columns in LINQ and also I want to take some of the columns:

```
public class Notification
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long NotificationId { set; get; }


    public NotificationType NotificationType { set; get; }


    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public UserProfile UserProfile { get; set; }


    public DateTime CreateDate { set; get; }



    public bool Notice { set; get; }


    public long NewsId { set; get; }


    public int RecipientId { get; set; }
}
```

I have written the following code, But displays all records:

```
var x=(from n in _Notification
                where n.RecipientId == id
                orderby n.CreateDate descending, n.UserId
                group new { n.UserId, n.NewsId}
                by new { n.UserId, n.NewsId, n.Notice, n.NotificationType, n.CreateDate, n.NotificationId, n.UserProfile } into g
                select new NotificationViewModel
                {
                    NewsId = g.Key.NewsId,
                    CauserId = g.Key.UserId,
                    CauserName = g.Key.UserProfile.Name,
                    CreateDate = g.Key.CreateDate,
                    Notice = g.Key.Notice,
                    NotificationId = g.Key.NotificationId,
                    NotificationType = g.Key.NotificationType,
                }).ToList();
```

I want to be grouped according to UserId and NewsId

Answer (score 1):

You get one listed instead of grouped list because at the end you have select statement while you should have group by at the end. Change your code like this:

```
var x=(from n in _Notification
            where n.RecipientId == id
            orderby n.CreateDate descending, n.UserId
            group new NotificationViewModel
            {
                NewsId = g.Key.NewsId,
                CauserId = g.Key.UserId,
                CauserName = g.Key.UserProfile.Name,
                CreateDate = g.Key.CreateDate,
                Notice = g.Key.Notice,
                NotificationId = g.Key.NotificationId,
                NotificationType = g.Key.NotificationType,
            }
            by new { n.UserId, n.NewsId}).ToList();
```

Comment: thank you. 
Now how do I convert the Ilist. (x is IGrouping, I kind of want IList IList<NotificationViewModel>)

Comment: x will be of type List<IGrouping<anonymousType,NotificationViewModel >>, so it is a list of lists of NotificationViewModel

Comment: IGrouping extends IEnumerable